# Create Table in LaTeX in the following format

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm relatively new to creating tables in Latex and I aim to create the following. Unfortunately, I'm not sure especially how to create the left block 'Np'. Any help is welcomed.

[image]

The following is my first approach using one of the examples mentioned in the comments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llr}  
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Numerical Comparison} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
$N_p$    & TV & Anisotropic & Isotropic\\
\midrule
20     &0.125   &0.151   &0.144\\
40     &0.065   &0.096   &0.088\\
60     &0.059   &0.077   &0.071\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Note that I actually desire to have (as in the table example) for each TV/Isotropic/Anisotropic a subbar with different parameters besides error (like correlation, Time).

Comment: You need the `multirow` package. Run `texdoc multirow` for more information. Run also `texdoc booktabs`.

Comment: If you don't mind having the $N_p$ heading not centered, the documentation of the booktabs package (https://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ctan.org/tex/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) has a very similar example.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay which example do you mean?

Comment: @Pazu: try typing in the code on page 5, and you should get the second table on page 2.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I copied it, and apparently it doesn't work. Do I need some special environment for this?

Comment: This example requires loading `array`.

Comment: @Bernard Okay, I managed to create it but I doesn't resemble the table I intended to create at all.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried in your question. Then we can look into it to find an error ... Do not forget to add the error message you get ...

Comment: You shoud post a small *compilable* example of what you've tried. Personally, I would use the `S` columntype from `siunitx` to have numbers aligned on the decimal dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since line-breaking inside cells isn't needed, I suggest you use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabularx` environment.

I would also align the numbers in the nine data columns on their respective decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup % localize scope of the next instruction
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. sapce
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    c *{3}{T{2.1}T{2.1}T{3.0}} }  
\toprule
$N_p$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Isotropic}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Inpainting Once}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Inpainting Twice} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& {error} & {correlation} & {time} & 
  {error} & {correlation} & {time} & 
  {error} & {correlation} & {time} \\ 
\midrule
10 & 13.6 & 98.4 & 113 & 12.4 & 98.7 & 285 & 12.3 & 98.7 & 411 \\
15 &  8.4 & 99.4 & 135 \\
20 &  6.2 & 99.7 & 140 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Pazu - I'm really not sure what to make of your comment. The code I posted generated the screenshot shown above, with absolutely no errors of any kind. 
All I can surmise is that you didn't copy and paste my code correctly. E.g., did you copy and paste the preamble instructions into the preamble of your document?

Comment: Do any of your packages have some dependency I should know of?

Comment: @Pazu - Your question is so broad as to be unanswerable. (There are thousands, maybe tens of thousands, of LaTeX packages out there!) Please do state which packages are loaded by *your* document.