# Correct code not compiling (in Texmaker): Due to dependencies?

Tags: errors, packages, compiling, siunitx, dependencies

My original goal was to create table with certain properties and I got a good answer here: [What I wanted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558091/create-table-in-latex-in-the-following-format). Unfortunately, running it in Texmaker did give me a fatal error. The code itself is correct though as I tried it in some Online LaTeX editor. I'm not sure why it doesn't compile. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup % localize scope of the next instruction
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. sapce
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    c *{3}{T{2.1}T{2.1}T{3.0}} }  
\toprule
$N_p$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Isotropic}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Inpainting Once}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Inpainting Twice} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& {error} & {correlation} & {time} & 
  {error} & {correlation} & {time} & 
  {error} & {correlation} & {time} \\ 
\midrule
10 & 13.6 & 98.4 & 113 & 12.4 & 98.7 & 285 & 12.3 & 98.7 & 411 \\
15 &  8.4 & 99.4 & 135 \\
20 &  6.2 & 99.7 & 140 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.

First error line:

```
Package: l3keys2e 2020-02-14 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l__siunitx_tmp_box=\box48
\l__siunitx_tmp_dim=\dimen159
\l__siunitx_tmp_int=\count183
! LaTeX3 Error: '\tl_to_lowercase:n' deprecated on 2018-03-05. Use
(LaTeX3) '\tex_lowercase:D '.
Type <return> to continue.
...
l.318 \tl_to_lowercase:n
{
LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
```

Comment: Pattern in TeX errors are mostly irrelevant. Only the _first_ error contains real information, the rest is TeX trying to go on. Your code runs on my machine but I've got an old distribution. It seems you have incompatible versions of `expl3` and `siunitx` but I'm guessing.

Comment: In a case like this it is a good idea to also provide the actual log file for the compilation of this exact example. If you by any change is using miktex remember to update it in **both** user and **admin** mode or you can end up in a situation where one have newer package versions than the other expects

Comment: Your example compiles just fine for me using an up to date TeXLive 2020

Comment: I have no errors with MikTeX, update MikTeX.

Comment: @daleif I think that the complete log-file is too long to share?

Comment: If the log is for this single MWE, you should be able to update your question with it. On my system it's about 250 lines. Additionally sniplets of logs aren't that useful in most cases.

Comment: as @campa suggested I have copied the first error (I hope) from the log-file

Comment: That log sniplet does not tell us anything other than you are using an out of date `siunitx`. That is unlikely to happen with TeXLive so again, please make sure your MikTeX is up to date in **both** user and admin mode!

Comment: @daleif Can you elaborate on user/admin mode? How does this come into play with Texmaker?

Comment: @Pazu no you don't!!! Texmaker is an **editor** it does not contain LaTeX. Texmaker enables you to write your LaTeX code and then when you ask Texmaker calls LaTeX for you. So LaTeX is installed sepatately. We can see which latex you use from the very start of the log file, hence why I keep asking for it.

Comment: @ Well, I have in fact installed siunitx today

Comment: Show the full log!

Comment: @Pazu that is the problem (and the log file would show details but you have not shown it) you have somehow installed a siunitx that is incompatible with the expl3 you have installed so you should update your tex installation so everything has matching versions.

Comment: So I will just copy the full log-file?

Comment: As we have been asking: show the log

Comment: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 38072.

Comment: The log for this small example? Then you have a seriously incompatible setup. As I mentioned, I only get 250 lines. Please send that entire log file to daleif@gmail.com

Comment: Issue seems to come from a local copy of `siunitx.sty` a version from 2012!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By analysing the OPs log file we find that MikTeX is loading an extra folder in which there is a `siunitx` version that identifies it self as

```
Package: siunitx 2012/07/16 v2.5f A comprehensive (SI) units package
```

which of course is not compatible with modern versions of the `expl3` packages.

If that extra root folder is not needed, then disable the extra root folder in the MikTeX settings.

In case there are stuff in the extra foloder that are needed, then rename the super old version of `siunitx.sty` in there.

Comment: You were absolutely right. In Miktex, I went to Settings and then to Directories. Removing this folder solved the issue for me. Much thanks again for taking your time